# How to check if appended slice is equal to a string?

Tags: string, go, slice

So the plan is to have a string such as "a" in the slice, and once that turns into "a100" for example then stop running a for loop which is adding numbers to the end of it. When I try the code below it says "(mismatched types []string and string)", is this because I have to convert the slice into a string? If so, how do I do that? Thanks.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var s []string
    s = append(s, "a")
    fmt.Println(s)
    for i := 0; i <= 1000; i++ {
        s = append(s, i)
        if s == "a10" {
            fmt.Println("Worked", s)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(s)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not certain what your plan is with this, but you may be better off using []byte not []string.

Comment: The end result is trying to create something similar to a nonce. So I will generate a hash and keep appending numbers from 1, 2, 3...123 etc... (not 0123 for example) until the hash begins with say 4 0's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert an `[]string` to a string` by doing:

```
import "strings"

//...

if strings.Join(s, "") == "a10" {
      fmt.Println("Worked", s)
} else {
      fmt.Println(s)
}
```

You also need to convert `i` (an int) to a `string`, most likely you would use `strconv.Itoa`.  In the end, you code would look something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/gD5b5XFimJ

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var s []string
    s = append(s, "a")
    fmt.Println(s)
    for i := 0; i <= 1000; i++ {
        s = append(s, strconv.Itoa(i))
        if strings.Join(s, "") == "a01" {
            fmt.Println("Worked", s)
            return
        } else {
            fmt.Println(s)
        }
    }
}
```

Although, you could also just not use an array and append to the string (or an []byte) directly...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var s := "a"
    fmt.Println(s)
    for i := 0; i <= 1000; i++ {
        s += strconv.Itoa(i)
        if s == "a01" {
            fmt.Println("Worked", s)
            return
        } else {
            fmt.Println(s)
        }
    }
}
```

To reset the array every time, just make the main method:

```
for i := 0; i <= 1000; i++ {
    s := []string{"a"}
    s = append(s, strconv.Itoa(i))
    if strings.Join(s, "") == "a10" {
        fmt.Println("Worked", s)
        return
    } else {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I left out I need to convert the i (int) to a string too. Can you do that a similar way?

Comment: Thank you for the updated comment. I forgot that I needed to get rid of the previously added (i) from the slice though. Otherwise I get things like [a 1 2 3] [a 1 2 3 4] etc. Instead of [a 1] [a 2]

Comment: Note that strings.Join() isn't exactly cheap, especially if the slice starts getting pretty long or has long strings in it.  It's FAR cheaper than appending using `+` (or `+=`), but the immutability of strings still means you're allocating an entire new byte array (with size equal to the sum of the lengths in the string slice) on every single strings.Join() call.